# Header and footer fixed with expander floating

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm building a page in XAML. On this page I want to make the header and footer fixed.
The content will have a scrool and will also have a floating button with the expander.

The code is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms">
    <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!-- MAIN CONTAINER -->
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" RowSpacing="0" BackgroundColor="#e6e6e6">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <!-- CUSTOM NAVBAR -->
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource DarkAccentColor}" HeightRequest="64">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <!-- BACK ICON -->
                    <ffimageloading:CachedImage Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" Margin="0,0,0,12"  VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Transparent" CacheType="All" FadeAnimationEnabled="false" Opacity="1" Source="{StaticResource BackArrowWhite}" Aspect="AspectFit">
                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding NavigateBackCommand}"/>
                        </ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                    </ffimageloading:CachedImage>

                    <!-- APP NAME -->
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="End" Margin="5,0,0,10" Text="{Binding PageTitle}" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="None" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }" />

                    <!-- SETTINGS ICON -->
                    <ffimageloading:CachedImage Grid.Column="2" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" Margin="0,0,10,12"  VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Transparent" CacheType="All" FadeAnimationEnabled="false" Opacity="1" Source="{StaticResource ThreeDotsWhite}" Aspect="AspectFit">
                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding NavigateToSettingsCommand}"/>
                        </ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                    </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
                </Grid>

                <!-- MAIN AREA -->
                <ScrollView Grid.Row=1" BackgroundColor="#e6e6e6" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0">
                    <!-- MAIN GRID -->
                    <Grid VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="4" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <!-- Expander One -->
                        <xct:Expander Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent" ExpandAnimationLength="500" CollapseAnimationLength="500" Padding="10,0,10,10">
                            <xct:Expander.Header>
                                <Grid VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="0,10,0,0">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Image Source="{ StaticResource CollapseUp }" HeightRequest="15" WidthRequest="15" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="5,5,0,0">
                                        <Image.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type xct:Expander}}, Path=IsExpanded}" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="{ StaticResource CollapseDown }" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Image.Triggers>
                                    </Image>

                                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="{StaticResource RobotoMonoRegular}" VerticalOptions="End" Margin="15,0,0,0" Text="Expander One" FontSize="18" FontAttributes="None" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="{ DynamicResource ServiceOrderInfoValueColor }" />
                                </Grid>
                            </xct:Expander.Header>
                            <xct:Expander.ContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <!-- SEPARATOR -->
                                        <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0.30" Margin="0,10" HeightRequest="0.8" Color="#9B9B9B"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </xct:Expander.ContentTemplate>
                        </xct:Expander>

                        <!-- Expander Two -->
                        <xct:Expander Grid.Row="3" Background="Transparent" ExpandAnimationLength="500" CollapseAnimationLength="500" Padding="10,0,10,10">
                            <xct:Expander.Header>
                                <Grid VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="0,10,0,0">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Image Source="{ StaticResource CollapseUp }" HeightRequest="15" WidthRequest="15" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="5,5,0,0">
                                        <Image.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type xct:Expander}}, Path=IsExpanded}" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="{ StaticResource CollapseDown }" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Image.Triggers>
                                    </Image>

                                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="{StaticResource RobotoMonoRegular}" VerticalOptions="End" Margin="15,0,0,0" Text="Expander Two" FontSize="18" FontAttributes="None" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="{ DynamicResource ServiceOrderInfoValueColor }" />
                                </Grid>
                            </xct:Expander.Header>
                            <xct:Expander.ContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </xct:Expander.ContentTemplate>
                        </xct:Expander>

                        <!-- Expander Three -->
                        <xct:Expander Grid.Row="5" Background="Transparent" ExpandAnimationLength="500" CollapseAnimationLength="500" Padding="10,0,10,10">
                            <xct:Expander.Header>
                                <Grid VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="0,10,0,0">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Image Source="{ StaticResource CollapseUp }" HeightRequest="15" WidthRequest="15" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="5,5,0,0">
                                        <Image.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type xct:Expander}}, Path=IsExpanded}" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="{ StaticResource CollapseDown }" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Image.Triggers>
                                    </Image>

                                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="{StaticResource RobotoMonoRegular}" VerticalOptions="End" Margin="15,0,0,0" Text="Expander Three" FontSize="18" FontAttributes="None" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="{ DynamicResource ServiceOrderInfoValueColor }" />
                                </Grid>
                            </xct:Expander.Header>
                            <xct:Expander.ContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <!-- SEPARATOR -->
                                        <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0.30" Margin="0,10" HeightRequest="0.8" Color="#9B9B9B"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </xct:Expander.ContentTemplate>
                        </xct:Expander>
                    </Grid>
                </ScrollView>

                <!-- Footer -->
                <Grid Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="White" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="20" Padding="0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <!-- YES BUTTON -->
                    <artina:Button BorderColor="#7b7b7b" BorderWidth="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="{StaticResource RobotoMonoBold}" Margin="15" FontSize="14" FontAttributes="Bold" Style="{StaticResource RatButtonStylePrevious}" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Text="Back" WidthRequest="160" Command="{Binding ToBack}"/>

                    <!-- NO BUTTON-->
                    <artina:Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="{StaticResource RobotoMonoBold}" Margin="15" FontSize="14" FontAttributes="Bold" Style="{StaticResource RatButtonStyleNext}" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Text="Next" WidthRequest="160" Command="{Binding ToNext}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <!-- Floating expander -->
        <Frame CornerRadius="30"
                    Padding="15"
                    Margin="0,0,15,40"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 1, AutoSize, AutoSize"               
                    VerticalOptions="End">

            <xct:Expander Rotation="180">

                <xct:Expander.Header>
                    <Label
                             Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"
                             Text="Item">

                        <Label.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger
                                     Binding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type xct:Expander}}, Path=IsExpanded}"
                                                       TargetType="Label" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="a" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Label.Triggers>

                    </Label>
                </xct:Expander.Header>

                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"
                                Text="01" />

                    <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"
                                Text="02" />

                    <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"
                                Text="03" />
                </StackLayout>

            </xct:Expander>

        </Frame>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

But I'm not able to make the footer fixed, there is always some conflict with my floating expander

[image]

Answer (score 1):

CollectionView Headers and Footers are not designed with the idea that they are supposed to stick to a particular area of the screen they are like screen the header and the footer of your list so if it contracts they come close to each other with it.

But if you want a View that sticks to the bottom of the screen regardless of what you add to it just use a Grid to do this instead.

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*,Auto">

  <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" >
   <!--Whatever view you wanna display...-->
  </StackLayout>

   <CollectionView Grid.Row= "1">
     ......
   </CollectionView >

   <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" >
     <!--Whatever view you wanna display...-->
   </StackLayout>

</Grid>
```

Hope this helps,

Feel free to ask me if you have queries

Comment: Inside each expander there is already a CollectionView. Is your proposal to leave all the content inside the CollectionView? and the floating button how should it look?

Comment: Wait why do you have a scrollview and then inside a collectionview.. Can you show me an example of the UI you wanna achieve and i can help you further

Comment: The main content is a grid, I have separated lines, the first and last are header and footer. The middle row has a scrollview with three expanders and each expander has collectionView
This is the UI of the page: https://www.figma.com/file/AWKeesvO6JSU2LwHzACKGC/Pe%C3%A7as?node-id=0%3A1

Comment: You don't need 3 collectionview's and a scrollview you should be doing all that in one CollectionView. something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GG10QPrRC3w&ab_channel=HoussemDellai

Comment: @Tiago - FreakyAli is giving a good solution. I'll comment that using `AbsoluteLayout` is overkill. Remove it. `Grid` will fill display, if it has one or more `*` rows. This is an easy layout to accompish.

Comment: i hope they will make an improvement to make it possible to stick header/footer https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9994

Comment: @Cfun They might or it might never happen, I mean there are 100's of these just sitting there in the XF library

Comment: @FreakyAli I understand the proposal, I will make this change. Just a question how is the floating button? Don't need AbsoluteLayout to work this type of button?

Comment: Why don't you finish this and then we can talk about that (No Absolute Layout is not mandatory)